# DirectX9 CreateDevice fails in C, but succeds in C++

Tags: c++, c, directx

I making a d3d9 app in C, but when trying to create a device object it fails in C, but its counterpart in C++ just works and returns S_OK.
C:

```
isOk = pD3D->lpVtbl->CreateDevice(pD3D, D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, d3dpParams.hDeviceWindow, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpParams, &lpDevice);
```

C++:

```
isOk = pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, d3dpParams.hDeviceWindow, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpParams, &lpDevice);
```

My guess lays in D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpParams
In C++ it's initialized with "= {}":

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpParams = {};
d3dpParams.Windowed = false;
d3dpParams.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
...
```

While in C you can only write ";":

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpParams;
d3dpParams.Windowed = false;
d3dpParams.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
...
```

*pD3D is IDirect3D9* created by Direct3DCreate9() which can't fail if I understand correctly.

It was originally done with gcc, but msvc gives exactly the same results.

Comment: The C equivalent of `={}` is to `memset` it to all zero bytes. Try that.

Comment: Use `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpParams = {0};`

Comment: so my guess was correct, indeed works, I didn't know that {} zeros memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `={}` initialization for a plain C struct only zeroes the memory.

Microsoft's own example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/creating-a-device recommends `ZeroMemory` for this:

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp; 

ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying reason why the `C` version doesn't work is that this:

`D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpParams;`

creates an uninitialized variable named `d3dpParams`.  Since it is uninitialized, any garbage data that the individual members are set to are being read by the `CreateDevice` function, thus causing erratic behavior.  You would have the same issue in C++, so this is not really C versus a C++ issue.

Since the issue is one of initialization, the C++ code does the initialization by setting all elements in the struct to `0` using the `{}` syntax.

Since `C` does not have such syntax to initialize a variable, you need to set all the members to `0`.  The functions `ZeroMemory`, `memset`, and similar `C` functions can be used to do this.

`ZeroMemory(&d3dpParams, sizeof(d3dpParams));`

Answer (score 0):

The zero-initializer in C++ is:

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpParams = {};
```

The equivalent initializer in C is:

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpParams = {0};
```

You don't have to call `ZeroMemory` or `memset`. Note that with a standards-conforming C compiler, the C++ version will generate a compiler warning, since empty initializers are not allowed in C. That's why the "0" is required.